# Minecraft won't download sound file calm3.ogg!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

right now I'm on vacation on my brother's computer and when I download Minecraft it works but when i press play it wont download calm3.ogg this is the error message

```
Name: calm3.ogg
URL: http://resources.download.minecraft.net/14/14ae57a6bce3d4254daa8be2b098c2d99743cc3f
Error details: Request error -101: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Filename on disk: e90c-b0f6-a01f-0e8c
Path: C:\Users\WEARE4~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e90c-b0f6-a01f-0e8c
Exists: file
```

I'm using version 1.7.10 but same happens on every other version

Comment: OMG I TRIED AGAIN AND IT WORKED THX!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is most frequently caused by antivirus, firewall or other type of software which scans downloads.

Try temporarily disabling your antivirus software.

Comment: I have windows defender and I disabled it but it still doesn't work it downloads every other file but not that one!